# bashscript is not getting invoked in current shell through crontab

Tags: cron, bash

everyting working as root user in linuxmint. my bashscript works perfectly as a single
script and generating logfile as well but it is not getting invoked in my current shell through crontab.

path of bashscript:  /root/Documents/mybashscript.sh

crontab line:

```
0.9 * * * * root /root/Documents/mybashscript.sh > /root/Documents/crontab.log
```

mybashscript.sh inside commands are as below:

```
#!/bin/bash
source /root/.profile
echo -n "Please enter your name: "
read name
TIME=‘date +%H‘
case $TIME in
0[6-9] | 1[01] ) echo -n "Good morning";;
12 ) echo -n "Good Noon";;
1[2-6] ) echo -n "Good Afternoon";;
1[7-9] ) echo -n "Good Evening";;
*) echo -n "Good Night";;
esac
echo " $name, Nice to meet you!"
```

Can anybody tell me how to trouble shoot.

Comment: what is this `root` doing: `0.9 * * * * root`? You should change that to `/bin/bash`

Answer (score 1):

First things first, I don't believe `0.9` is a valid minute indicator. I think you probably want `0-9` (depending on when you want it to run of course).

Secondly, you appear to have an extraneous `root` in your `cron` entry (the first one following the final `*`).

Thirdly, `cron` jobs don't really work that well for interactive input like:

```
read name
```

so I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve there.

Comment: Good point +1, but I suppose one could make it work by piping in some input `< "Foo" > /cron.log`